# YouTube stopVideo() is pausing instead of stopping?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

My website is running Bootstrap 3.0 and I have an intro video and full length video hosted on YouTube that I am trying to implement. The intro video autoplays when the page is loaded, and then I have a button that opens up a modal window with the full video with audio.

I would like to stop the video completely on close of the modal window so that if they click the button to open it again, the video starts from the beginning. Unfortunately, the stopVideo function doesn't seem to be working how I would expect. Basically, it's just pausing the video, so if I open the modal back up, the video starts playing right from where it left off.

How can I make it so that the video stops and starts from the beginning if it's reopened?

Here is my current code:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#placeholder')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
  $('#full')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'playVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#full')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
  $('#placeholder')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'playVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `seekTo` to get back to the begining of the video when the modal is open.
An play the video after the `seekTo`

[Doc from API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=fr)

> player.seekTo(seconds:Number, allowSeekAhead:Boolean):Void
>
> Seeks to a specified time in the video. If the player is paused when
>   the function is called, it will remain paused. If the function is
>   called from another state (playing, video cued, etc.), the player will
>   play the video. The seconds parameter identifies the time to which the
>   player should advance.
>
> The player will advance to the closest keyframe before that time
>   unless the player has already downloaded the portion of the video to
>   which the user is seeking. In that case, the player will advance to
>   the closest keyframe before or after the specified time as dictated by
>   the seek() method of the Flash player's NetStream object. (See Adobe's
>   documentation for more information.)
>
> The allowSeekAhead parameter determines whether the player will make a
>   new request to the server if the seconds parameter specifies a time
>   outside of the currently buffered video data.
>
> We recommend that you set this parameter to false while the user drags
>   the mouse along a video progress bar and then set it to true when the
>   user releases the mouse. This approach lets a user scroll to different
>   points of a video without requesting new video streams by scrolling
>   past unbuffered points in the video. When the user releases the mouse
>   button, the player advances to the desired point in the video and
>   requests a new video stream if necessary.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, forgot to report back, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem,spend hours digging into it. however I didn't find a sure reason, but the following reason may be it:

> ("stopVideo()") Stops and cancels loading of the current video.

and

> Important: Unlike the pauseVideo function, which leaves the player in the paused (2) state, the stopVideo function could put the player into any not-playing state, including ended (0), paused (2), video cued (5) or unstarted (-1).

This is quoted from [the YouTube API page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls)

But I'm confused by this, because even if the background mechanism are not the same between stop and pause api, they act still identical(sometimes), so I'm still confused and curious about the real usage of stopVideo().